# Remove unused files from ActiveStorage+DirectUpload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js, rails-activestorage

Consider the following example:

1. I have a form that includes a multiple files input;
2. The input file uses ActiveStorage and DirectUpload to upload files automatically as soon as they are included;
3. After adding some files they are uploaded automatically;
4. I never click the `submit` button so those files are never used nor accessible anywhere;

Does Rails support some built-in mechanism for removing these files or is something we have to implement ourselves?

Seems rather trivial to perform a DoS by continuously uploading files until something breaks.

**Update 1**

Forgot to mention that the example I'm following uses a 3rd party library (Dropzone in this case) and follow the example from the [official documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#integrating-with-libraries-or-frameworks).

According to the documentation after a file upload we inject a hidden input field with the id of the uploaded blob.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer of Chiperific is good, since DirectUpload is executed in the submit there is little time for the requests to fail.

I mention request**s** because as far as i understand it, the process is like this:

1. The user selects a file from his computer and fills the rest form.
2. DirectUpload uploads the file to the storage.
3. The backend receives the body and updates the attachment and either creates or updates a model.

So, what happens if the file upload is successful but model validation is not? you would end up with a file in the storage without his corresponding model or with dirty one.

More information here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31985

The answer then is no, rails does not have a mechanism of removing this files automatically. I guess you could check if the model creation/update was successful and remove the file manually if not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your premise is incorrect.

> 2. The input file uses ActiveStorage and DirectUpload to *upload files automatically as soon as they are included*;

According to [the docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads):

> Active Storage, with its included JavaScript library, supports uploading directly from the client to the cloud.

and

> That's it! Uploads begin upon form submission.

So the point of Direct Storage seems to be to bypass some Rails ActiveStorage things and go straight to the service. BUT, it still doesn't happen until the form is submitted.

The example on [the non-edge docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/active_storage_overview.html#example) shows the user clicking "Submit" before the files are actually uploaded.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I forgot to mention an important aspect which is integration with other libraries (like Dropzone). Basically section 10.5 of the ActiveStorage documentation.

Comment: So you're right that you COULD program the JS to immediately upload the attachment once selected, but I think you've made a good use-case for NOT doing this. This risk is not inherent out of the box, you'd have to manually introduce this error, which I think is not Rails' fault. They can't be held responsible for me making my own app do something dangerous.

Comment: Exactly. So why document this approach on the official rails guide without mentioning the security implications? Seem rather incomplete...

Comment: Good point, looking at 10.5, they are handing you the code to do this without noting the DoS potential. Looks like you're supposed to open a pull request on the guide source code: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/guides, https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#contributing-to-the-rails-documentation